# React Native: How to prevent state variable from being removed on hot reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a state variable `a` in my React Native app that gets pulled from an API when the component mounts, and then another called `b` that gets set once `a` is set. So `a` is set like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchA();
}
```

and then `b` is set like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.b !== this.props.b){
    this.setState({
      a: this.props.b;
    })
  }
}
```

**The Problem:**

I have hot reloading on. When I save something, the screen hot reloads and `this.state.b` disappears. How can I avoid this?